# PHP: imap_savebody() breaks long lines

Tags: php, email, imap

I attempt to parse an email message whose body is in csv format.

The email supposedly has this content:

```
,111111111111111,Abcde Abcd,,abcde@abcdefghi.com.au,61352722827,13/04/2012,14/04/2011,Abcd Abcdefghi,
,111111111111111,Abcde Abcd,,abcde@abcdefghi.com.au,61352722827,13/04/2012,14/04/2011,Abcd Abcdefghi,
```

But imap_savebody() saves it like this:

```
,111111111111111,Abcde
Abcd,,abcde@abcdefghi.com.au,61352722827,13/04/2012,14/04/2011,Abcd
Abcdefghi,
,111111111111111,Abcde
Abcd,,abcde@abcdefghi.com.au,61352722827,13/04/2012,14/04/2011,Abcd
Abcdefghi,
```

The encoding is 7BIT as outputted by imap_fetchstructure. Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: What's wrong with it? The content looks correct other than your text is wrapping where there spaces are or have the spaces been replaced with new line characters?

Comment: I want it to appear the way it was intended to appear.  Strangely, if I remove the spaces, it sometimes breaks on the the commas. imap_fetchbody() reads it fine though.

Comment: it seems that line breaks are being added where there are spaces because the lines are too long in the original email: http://emailgarage.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/line-length-in-plain-text-emails/ I'm unsure why imap_fetchbody is unaffected.